# 'float' object is not iterable using shift function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to shift from one column to another

```
rows = df[df.iloc[:,4].notnull()]
cols = df.iloc[:,4]
df.loc[rows,columns] = df.loc[rows,cols].shift(1, axis=1)
```

I have attached the dataset as image, here I also have one column with value as 100%.

It cannot shift my column, it is throwing the 'float object not iterable'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to trigger the exact same error, but let me just give a dummy example to show what is going wrong, and how you may perform your operation correctly. Here's a dummy `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'a': [np.nan,2,3], 'b':[1,np.nan,np.nan], 'c': [np.nan,2,3], 'd':[1,np.nan,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

     a    b    c    d
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN  3.0  NaN
```

*Goal*: replace `NaNs` in `df.d` with `non-NaNs` from `df.c`. If I understand correctly, you were trying as follows:

```
rows = df[df.iloc[:,2].notnull()]
cols = df.iloc[:,2]
df.loc[rows,cols] = df.loc[rows,cols].shift(1, axis=1)
```

In this particular case, the last line will throw this error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',)], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

(side note: your own error is perhaps related to `df.loc[rows,columns]`, what is `columns`? You mean `cols` surely.)

Now, in this example `rows` is actually a `pd.DataFrame`, and `cols` is a `pd.Series`, so it already goes wrong on the selection. You might think, you could fix this by using `df.loc[rows.index,cols.name]`, but this simply generates a new `pd.Series`:

```
print(df.loc[rows.index,cols.name])

1    2.0
2    3.0
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

For obivous reasons, you cannot `shift` a `pd.Series` columnwise, because it only has `axis 0`, i.e. it is one-dimensional.

So, let's try a slightly different approach:

```
col = 2 # column 'c'
rows = df[df.iloc[:,col].notnull()].index # Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')

# now select from the df col c AND following (colon) and assign it the columnwise shift
df.iloc[rows,col:] = df.iloc[rows,col:].shift(1, axis=1)

print(df)

     a    b   c    d
0  NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0
1  2.0  NaN NaN  2.0
2  3.0  NaN NaN  3.0
```

Imagine that we only want to shift `non-NaNs` from `df.a` to replace `NaNs` in `df.b`, then we write:

```
col = 0 # column 'a'
rows = df[df.iloc[:,col].notnull()].index # Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')

# now select from the df col a AND b (+2)
df.iloc[rows,col:col+2] = df.iloc[rows,col:col+2].shift(1, axis=1)

print(df)

    a    b    c    d
0 NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
1 NaN  2.0  2.0  NaN
2 NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN
```

Hope that makes some sense, and offers a solution.